# volume buttons have no effect when playing through ear piece

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin Forms Android app I'm sending audio through the ear piece instead of the normal speaker. I'm doing something like:

```
myMediaPlayer.SetAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder().SetLegacyStreamType(Stream.VoiceCall).Build());
```

The deprecated version of the above is

```
myMediaPlayer.SetAudioStreamType(Stream.VoiceCall);
```

Either way, this seems to work (though, if there is a better way, please let me know).
HOWEVER, **I cannot control the volume**. The sound correctly comes out of the ear speaker only, but it is at a constant volume, ignoring my volume key presses (though the volume meter displays on the screen going up and down as a press the buttons). ... (for clarification, I'm not trying to control the volume programatically, I simply want the device to adjust the volume as one would expect.)

Any help?

**UPDATE**

I've also tried this code:

```
myMediaPlayer.SetAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder().SetContentType(AudioContentType.Music).SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.VoiceCommunication).Build());
```

I have two goals:

1. Play only out of the ear piece (or headphones if attached)
2. Be able to control the volume (which I thought would be a given)

**UPDATE with Code Sample**

The following will play through the earpiece, but not change volume.

```
        public void Play(string url)
        {
            var myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            myMediaPlayer.SetDataSource(url);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                myMediaPlayer.SetAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder().SetContentType(AudioContentType.Music).SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.VoiceCommunication).Build());
            else
                myMediaPlayer.SetAudioStreamType(Stream.VoiceCall);

            myMediaPlayer.Prepare();
            myMediaPlayer.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Try to set the `StreamType` as  `Stream.Music` .

Comment: I need to audio to only go through the ear piece, not the main speaker.

Comment: Did you test it? Or you can provide the sample and I will check it on my side .

Comment: Yes, I've tested it. My primary goal is to have audio go through the ear piece only. However, not being able to control the volume is a deal-breaker.

Comment: You can provide the sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I added a code sample in my post. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202776/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-donny-kwitty).